# MySQL: Can't give tables a name in Upper Camel Case (Pascal Case)

Tags: mysql, naming-conventions, camelcasing, pascalcasing

I read that it is best practise to have table names in Pascal Case (ThisIsMyTableName).
Therefor I would like to change my tables in MySQL. But neither phpmyadmin, nore SQL Manager 2005 for MySQL will let me. The names stay to appear in lowercase, as if I didn't to a change at all.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: I am assuming you are on Windows?

Comment: Pekka: Is that relevant?

Comment: @Gabe: yes, it is. Windows is not case-sensitive when it comes to MySQL table names, whereas other operating systems generally are.

Comment: I disagree that this is best practice in MySQL, especially since case-sensitivity in MySQL table names is dependent on the underlying system. Just keep them lowercase and use_underscores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advice against mixed case because of problems with case sensitivity. A fully tested solution on one platform where case doesn't matter may actually fail when deployed on a platform where case DOES matter. For that reason alone I suggest sticking with either all caps or all lower case.
I use lower case because it is easier on the eye and make spelling errors easier to spot in fixed width fonts used in most editors.

Comment: I didnt know that the support of case sensivity in MySQL is dependet of the underlying Operating System. I guess I go for underscore!

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to take care of this is to add the following to your .ini file

```
lower_case_table_names=2
```

`2` is the significance here for Windows.  You can read more about it here [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use `RENAME`

example:

```
RENAME TABLE this_is_my_table_name TO ThisIsMyTableName;
```

details : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-table.html

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL, you can [quote the table names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) everywhere to make them case preserving and sensitive.

```
`MyTableName`
```

Comment: @PHPst:  You would have to do that when creating the table and then every time afterwards.