# mysql: service stops when lower_case_table_names is in 0

Tags: mysql, service

I have a problem with mysql 8.0.25.

I need Camel names in the tables and I am setting lower_case_table_names to 0 to do that.

lower_case_table_names takes in theory three values 0, 1 or 2.

Why is not working when I start the service in windows? it is giving me an error. Only works if I set lower_case_table_names to 1 or 2.

[image]

the error is this:

The service MYSQL80 in the local machine started and after it stopped. Some services stops automatically if they aren't used for no service or program

Comment: 'You should not set this variable to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file names (such as Windows or macOS). - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: all names I am setting as Pascal like MyTable MySql converts to lowercase, several sites tells to make Pascal names I should put to 0

Comment: I would prefer the manual over all other sources..and search for myqsl pascal case eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360770/mysql-cant-give-tables-a-name-in-upper-camel-case-pascal-case